# How can I run a batch file in an isolated environment?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, environment-variables

Changes to the environment made by a batch file persist in the calling cmd.exe's environment.

Assume `set.bat`:

```
SET MYVAR=42
```

Then in `cmd.exe`, I type and see:

```
C:\Users\Me>.\set.bat
C:\Users\Me>echo %MYVAR%
42
```

If I have a batch file (offered by someone else and way out of my skill set to edit) which configures the environment in a non-idempotent manner, and I execute it multiple times within one session of the command prompt, this can cause undesired behavior.

How can I run a batch file in an isolated environment, which won't rig the environment of cmd.exe? I emphasize that in accomplishing this, it is important that all console output is retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend editing the script and prepending the [`SETLOCAL` command](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html).

Alternatively, run a batch script in a [child `cmd` instance](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) as follows:

```
cmd /c .\set.bat
```

The environment variable values are inherited by the new CMD session while parent environment keeps unchanged.

Comment: I had actually seen the docs on `/c` but they didn't mention that output would be retained.